# Win32com: com_error

Tags: python, excel, win32com

Today I tried to use python to create a pivot table, most steps has been successed, but when the program running to fill the datefield, there alway s error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04DPl.png)

Actually I didn't know what the reason is

Comment: Hi, instead of posting a link to the image can you post the code that you ran (at least the lines creating the pivot table) so someone can better diagnose the issue?  You can use three backticks to create a code block

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.